# Operand type conflicts (char-string)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to create a droplist for users to select a month on. The droplist in itself works, but whenever I try to get the value of it, it fails. I think the easiest way to explain it is to show my code and the error message, since I'm not sure how else I would go about it.

Error message:

> CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

HTML with the dropdown list:

```
<h4 class="monthYear">
            <form action="WebForm1.aspx" method="get">
                <select name="monthList">
                    <option class="month">Januari</option>
                    <option class="month">Februari</option>
                    <option class="month">Mars</option>
                    <option class="month">Maj</option>
                    <option class="month">Juli</option>
                    <option class="month">Juni</option>
                    <option class="month">Augusti</option>
                    <option class="month">Oktober</option>
                    <option class="month">September</option>
                    <option class="month">November</option>
                    <option class="month">December</option>
                </select>

                    <input type="submit" name="setMonth" value="Visa" />
                </form>

            </h4>
```

C# code where I try to get whatever they selected from the list:

```
<% 
     var Januari = Request["Januari"];
     var Februari = Request["Februari"]; 
     var monthList = Request["monthList"];

     foreach (var month in monthList)
     {
         if (month == "Januari") <-- This == is what it doesn't seem to like.
         {
               Response.Write("Working");
               var setYear = 2015;
               var setMonth = 1;
         }

     } 

 %>
```

Comment: `monthList` is `string` but `month` is `char` and you can't use `==` between them. What do you achieve exactly?

Comment: You can write `if (month.ToString() == "Januari")`. But check that month is not null before that.

Comment: That will always yield `false` since a single char can't have a length other than `1`. So `Januari` will be out of its range a little...

Comment: Simply remove the foreach...

Comment: @SonerGönül Did not know that nor how to convert it, so yeah :P

Comment: I think his monthlist has problem, what he is trying to achieve is to request list of all months, but somehow he is just getting characters from the `Request` statement.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait Would it have been that simple, though?

Comment: I mean, i donu understand much about asp. Net. But from what i do remember monthList holds the selected value and thus the name of the month. So im probably wrong because the way i see it the foreach is useless...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monthList` is a `string`, and by doing an `foreach` on it, you get `char`s.

I guess you want to split the `monthList` on something, a `;` maybe:

```
foreach (var month in monthList.Split(';'))
{ }
```

Now, `month` is a `string`.

If the returned value isn't a list of anything, you simply might want to drop the `foreach` at all.

Comment: Got to wait a few minutes, but this fixed it and returned everything that needed to be. Cheers. Unbelievably fast to!